# Laravel Collection Filter By Multiple Concatenated Unique Fields

Tags: laravel, collections

I have a model download which has two three properties. Those properties are 'id' , 'user_id' , 'file_id'.

Whenever a user downloads a file a download record is created.

I want to grab all downloads that have both a unique file_id and unique user_id.

How is this accomplished.

Comment: You can use `groupBy` method.

Comment: How do you record download records?

Comment: @Can Celik by way of Eloquent.

Comment: @Jilson Thomas I would like to maintain the integrity of the collection in its object state.

Answer (score 4):

A collection might come from a relationship and needs filtering afterward. Below is a tested working solution in laravel 5.7 and most probably in later versions also:

```
$unique = $collection->unique(function ($item)
{
      return $item['brand'] . $item['model'];
});
```

Here is an article about this: http://laravel.at.jeffsbox.eu/laravel-5-eloquent-collection-methods-unique

Comment: This worked perfectly and succinctly. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `groupBy` method.

```
$downloads = DB::table('downloads')
            ->groupBy('file_id')
            ->groupBy('user_id')
            ->get();
```

**OR**

You can use the `distinct` method.

```
$downloads = DB::table('downloads')->distinct()->get();
```

Comment: Fair enough, how about using a laravel collection?

Comment: You are getting a collection through this method. What exact have you in your mind?

Comment: Something like:
\Download:all()->unique('user_id')->unique('file_id')->keyBy('file_id');

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: collection ->items [
1 => array(data)
2 => array(data)

];

The response should only include downloads that have distinct values within the combined file_id and user_id values.

i.e
1,1 //good
1,2//good
2,2//good
1,1//bad

Comment: I should be able to iterate the collection.
foreach($collection as $item) and the items should all be of the class Download